# Getting Cassandra tombstone_warn_threshold error

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

We have a Cassandra setup on our production. There are couple of tables with around 20M records in it. To reduce the number of records we deleted the unwanted records and have also set up ttl to remove data after some time. We have setup the grace period to 1 day now. We have also ran nodetool repair on each Cassandra node (one at a time). We have total 5 nodes in cluster with replication_factor as 3. Cassandra version is 2.1.14

In  Cassandra log I constantly see the below error:

```html
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-33] 2017-02-23 06:09:02,617 SliceQueryFilter.java:320 - Read 207 live and 3059 tombstone cells in event for key: 101:10001Njh:22017 (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 5000 columns were requested, slices=[-]
```

I ran the command  nodetool cfhistograms myekyspace event; and below is the output of the same

[image]

I not able to analyze the above output fully, but I do know the sstable  count is too high.

Any idea as to what we can do to fix this or optimize our Cassandra .

java heap size is set to 8 GB and we are using CMS garbage collection.

[image]

Output of  nodetool cfstats mykeyspace.event

Table Structure

```js
@chris-lohfink  - Updated the question with the cfstats details and 
CREATE TABLE vcs.events (
    v_id text,
    c_id text,
    e_month int,
    sid text,
    e_id timeuuid,
    cr_p_id text,
    e_bucket text,
    e_media map<text, text>,
    e_meta map<text, text>,
    e_met map<text, double>,
    tag set<text>,
    etime timestamp,
    etype text,
    isfin boolean,
    r_mode text,
    state text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((v_id, c_id, e_month), sid, e_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (sid ASC, e_id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 86400
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX events_id_idx ON mykeyspace.event (e_id);
CREATE INDEX events_type_idx ON mykeyspace.event (etype);
CREATE INDEX events_finalized_idx ON mykeyspace.event (isfin);
CREATE INDEX idx_state ON mykeyspace.event (state);
```

Comment: did you try `nodetool compact`

Comment: nodetool repair does compaction too. I see the compaction logs in cassandra log.

Comment: @chris-lohfink can you help with this?

Comment: http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCompact.html... Just try compaction, after compaction tombstone should not be there

Comment: use manual compaction with caution. It will create one large sstable that possibly will never be compacted again.

Comment: can you include `nodetool cfstats` for that table? also table schema including compaction strategy

Comment: @chris-lohfink  - Updated the question with the cfstats details

Comment: One more thing is around 300K records are deleted daily on this table

Answer (score 0):

When you delete data in Cassandra the data, it is not removed immediately, instead Cassandra creates tombstones indicating the row/column is deleted. Tombstones are stored till the gc_grace_seconds.

In your case you have 300K records deleted daily, which indicated more tombstones are created and affecting your performance. You should work on your data model to avoid this errors.
See the slides from 34 to 42 about deletes and TTL in http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/8-axel-liljencrantz-23204252

Also see the impact of data models on tombstones from below Cassandra docs:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets